# Make Non-Domain Machines Trust Self Signed Certificate

Tags: windows, ssl-certificate, windows-server-2016

Background:

At my company we are running ERP software on our local network that is hosted from a windows server.

The catch is that the client code (run in Chrome) requires that the site is loaded via https.

To fix this, I self signed a certificate for the server and updated the domain users to trust this certificate.

The issue arises with computers that are not *technically* a part of the domain, but are still needing access to the ERP. (Phones, Tablets, Etc)

These users can still access the app via "Advanced->Proceed To Site (Unsafe)" but this is a little clunky in practive.

Is there a way to make sure that all machines on your network automatically trust the certificate regardless of them being a domain user?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to make sure that all machines on your network
> automatically trust the certificate regardless of them being a domain
> user?

No. You'll need to import the certificate into the non-domain computers.

Comment: And actually install them on each pc?

Comment: Yes. I'm assuming you used Group Policy to import them into the domain joined computers. You can't use Group Policy on the non-domain joined computers because they aren't joined to the domain. You'll have to manually import the certificate or script the import and automate that, if you use some type of RMM to manage these machines.